# Como pasar un valor de un query a componente livewire?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

necesito de su ayuda. tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" wire:model="id_personal" value="{{$usuario[0]->personal}}">
<label for="">Aporte</label>
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" name="id_concepto_pago" wire:model="id_concepto_pago">
    <option>Elija una Opcion</option>
    @foreach($concepto as $con)
      <option value="{{$con->id}}">{{$con->descripcion}}</option>
    @endforeach
  </select>
  @error('id_concepto_pago') <span id="error">{{$message}}</span> @enderror
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="">Cantidad</label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control" wire:model="cantidad" placeholder="Ingrese una Cantidad">
  @error('cantidad') <span id="error">{{$message}}</span> @enderror
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="">Fecha</label>
  <input type="date" class="form-control" wire:model="fecha">
  @error('fecha') <span id="error">{{$message}}</span> @enderror
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="">Referencia</label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control" wire:model="referencia" placeholder="Colocar 0 si fue pago personal">
  @error('referencia') <span id="error">{{$message}}</span> @enderror
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="">Imagen</label>
  <input type="file" name="imagen" value="" wire:model="imagen">
  @error('imagen') <span id="error">{{$message}}</span> @enderror
</div>
```

pero el codigo de:  no funciona, todos los demas si. cuando le quito el wire:model="personal" el input me da el valor correcto.

public $id_personal;

tengo la variable publica.

este es el query que uso:

```
$usuario = DB::table('personal as p')
                  ->join('users as u','u.id','p.id_usuario')
                  ->select('p.id as personal','p.nombre','u.id as usuario')
                  ->where('u.id','=',$id)
                  ->get();
```

public function render()
{
$id = Auth::id();
$aporte = DB::table('aportes as ap')
->join('concepto_pago as cp','cp.id','=','ap.id_concepto_pago')
->join('personal as p','p.id','=','ap.id_personal')
->select('ap.*','cp.descripcion','cp.activo as con_activo','p.nombre','p.activo as p_activo')
->where('p.id_usuario','=',$id)

```
                ->orderBy('fecha','desc')
                ->paginate(5);
  $concepto = Concepto::all();
  $usuario = DB::table('personal as p')
              ->join('users as u','u.id','p.id_usuario')
              ->select('p.id as personal','p.nombre','u.id as usuario')
              ->where('u.id','=',$id)
              ->get();
  
  return view('livewire.Aportes.aporte-component',compact('aporte','concepto','usuario'));

}
```

Comment: Puedes mostrarnos tu método `render()`?

Comment: ya lo agregue en la publicacion original

Answer (score 1):

Estás teniendo un conflicto entre `wire:model` y el valor que le pasas con `{{$usuario[0]->personal}}`. Para solucionar dicho problema debes quitar `value="{{$usuario[0]->personal}}"` de tu `<input>`. Luego, en tu componente, en el método `mount()`, agrega lo siguiente:

```
public function mount()
{
    $usuario = DB::table('personal as p')
              ->join('users as u','u.id','p.id_usuario')
              ->select('p.id as personal','p.nombre','u.id as usuario')
              ->where('u.id','=',$id)
              ->get();

    $this->id_personal = $usuario->personal;
}
```

Obviamente, debes tener una propiedad pública llamada:

```
public $id_personal;
```

Comment: peor no tengo un metodo mount()

Comment: Crealo, si revisas la documentación lo encontrarás https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties#introduction, ahora lo agrego a mi respuesta

Comment: Gracias. me sirvió muy bien.